# How do I avoid a black screen before startup?

Tags: android, android-activity, load

I created a loadpage with a background and a progress bar and when it finishes loading, it starts the main class but the loading screen is not showing up. It is just a black screen while it loads and then the main screen. I put all the work in the onResume and I also tried onStart with no luck

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loadpage);
    //get rid of title bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(1);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    words = WordList.sharedWordList(this);

    if(generatedLevels==null)
    {
        generatedLevels  = new ArrayList<PuzzleMZLen>();
    }
    if(!p.isAlive())
    {
        p.start();          
    }


    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated - Are you sure you want to call super.onStart() in the onResume() method?

Comment: what is xml on R.layout.loadpage if is black just change the background i think.

Comment: @sqrfv i just forgot to change it. same thing happened

Comment: @subspider - loadpage has a picture background and a progress bar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this kind of work.Your layout is populated after the completion of the loading.So you are watching black screen.

Use `onPreExecute` of `AsyncTask` class to show the progress bar. And write loading code in the `doInBackground` method.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely use AsyncTask for this. I had the same thing going for my app, and here's my code:

```
private class getAllData extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Cursor> {
    protected void onPreExecute () {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Directory.this, "", 
                "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Context... params) {
        DirectoryTransaction.doDepts();

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor c) {

        for(int i = 0 ; i < DeptResults.length ; i++){
            deptsAdapter.add(DeptResults[i][0]);            
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

`onPreExecute` method loads a ProgressDialog that just shows "Loading. Please wait...". `doInBackground` does what was making my app load (in my case grabbing and parsing text from a server) and then `onPostExecute` is filling a spinner then dismissing the ProgressDialog. You'll want some thing different for a progress BAR, but the AsyncTask will be very similar. Call it in `onCreate` with new `getAllData.execute(this);`

Comment: tanks for this. it helps a lot

Comment: Took me a while to get it working how I needed it to, but it isn't all that hard. Check out the android dev documents on progressdialogs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good way how to create a good splash activity.

To prevent ANR you should move all data loading outside of UI thread as it was mentioned at other answers. Please use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or any other kind of multi-threading for that.

However to remove annoying black screen which shows for few moments on some slow devices you need to do next steps:

1. Create `bg_splash` drawable. It will be shown instead of black background just in time activity shows to user. For example it can be brand logo on brand color background.
2. Create a splash screen theme and put it into `/res/values/themes.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>   
       <style name="MyApp.Splash" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar">
           <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_splash</item>
       </style>
   </resources>
   ```
3. Don't forget assign created theme to splash activity by updating `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.example.myapp"
       android:versionCode="1"
       android:versionName="1" >

       ...

       <application>
           <activity
               android:name=".SplashActivity"
               android:theme="@style/MyApp.Splash" >
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           <activity>
           ...
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```